# IllegalStateException for recording a video using media recorder

Tags: android, video-capture, mediarecorder

```
 captureButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```

---

The following part is not working: (1) -- it asks for a context to create a new Preview

```
              //  mPreview = new Preview(,mMediaRecorder);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                //setContentView(mPreview);
```

---

The following part is not working: (2)

```
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                return isRecording = true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception, and could you please clarify what you mean by the parts that are not working.  What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: when i long press the capture button, it should record a video. the illegal state exception error points to the mMediaRecorder.start() line